# "undefined reference" error from static lib of external parquet project

Tags: linux, cmake, linker, parquet

I want to link expernal 'parquet' project ( https://github.com/apache/arrow/tree/master/cpp ) as part of my current project on Linux.

For this purposes I ran cmake of parquet with such parameters

```
cd build_parquet
cmake -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Release -DARROW_PARQUET=ON  \
 -DBoost_NO_BOOST_CMAKE=TRUE -DBoost_NO_SYSTEM_PATHS=TRUE -DBOOST_ROOT=${BOOST_BUILD_DIR}/include  -DBOOST_LIBRARYDIR=${BOOST_BUILD_DIR}/lib/boost -DARROW_BOOST_USE_SHARED=OFF -DBOOST_INCLUDEDIR=${BOOST_BUILD_DIR}/include/boost ..

cmake --build . --config Release
```

// There are a lot of dependencies except boost, but only boost required to be installed on system, since other could be downloaded and installed by cmake script

Project successfully compiled. I got executable which could launch, generated static libs libarrow.a, libparquet.a, shared libraries libarrow.so, libparquet.so

In my main project I want to use such libraries and I use such commands in cmake to find them

```
find_path(PARQUET_INCLUDE_DIR NAMES arrow/api.h PATHS ${PARQUET_DIR}/src)

find_library(PARQUET_LIBRARY_RELEASE NAMES parquet.a
              PATHS build_parquet/release/Release/ )

find_library(ARROW_LIBRARY_RELEASE NAMES arrow.a
             PATHS build_parquet/release/Release/ )

set(PARQUET_LIBRARIES_RELEASE ${PARQUET_LIBRARY_RELEASE} ${ARROW_LIBRARY_RELEASE} )

include(FindPackageHandleStandardArgs)
find_package_handle_standard_args(Parquet DEFAULT_MSG PARQUET_INCLUDE_DIR
                                  ${PARQUET_LIBRARIES_RELEASE } )
```

That's work okay, libraries and includes are found.

Then I link this libraries to my project

```
target_link_libraries(${myExe} ${PARQUET_LIBRARIES_RELEASE} ${mySomeOtherLibraries} )
```

after this I got enormous amount of linker errors such that

```
libparquet.a(column_writer.cc.o): In function `apache::thrift::transport::TMemoryBuffer::~TMemoryBuffer()':
column_writer.cc:(.text._ZN6apache6thrift9transport13TMemoryBufferD0Ev[_ZN6apache6thrift9transport13TMemoryBufferD5Ev]+0x3): undefined reference to `vtable for apache::thrift::transport::TMemoryBuffer'
.....
```

so that's what I don't understand much, why lib compiled well in parquet project itself but has a lot of unresolved now, when I use it to link in my own project? Moreover I compiled project for windows and when I did the same things, but with arrow.lib and parquet.lib (instead of libparquet.a and libarrow.a ) things worked fine! I was needed only to put arrow.dll, parquet.dll to executables to run project. But in Linux I've already crashed my head

So, why it doesn't work, what I should do to finally link the project with library ?

**Update**

I found the problem, I had to link libraries with adding .so files (not only .a files) like this

```
find_library(PARQUET_LIBRARY_RELEASE NAMES parquet.so parquet.a
             PATHS build_parquet/release/Release/ )

find_library(ARROW_LIBRARY_RELEASE NAMES arrow.so arrow.a
            PATHS build_parquet/release/Release/ )

set(PARQUET_LIBRARIES_RELEASE ${PARQUET_LIBRARY_RELEASE} ${ARROW_LIBRARY_RELEASE} )
```

Project is builded. So now the question is, why I need to add .so files to linker (in Windows only static .lib are enough), is it always a case when I build project in Linux ? Is order of linkage important ( .so files first and .a files next ? )

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Here we expect the error message, which describes your problem, to be **in the question post** itself, **as text**, not *linked* as *image*. Please, [edit] your post and fix that issue. Also, with such fragmented code it is difficult to say where is your error. It is much better to provide [mcve], which demonstrates your problem. Some notes about your problems: Linux uses `.a` libraries, `.lib` ones has no sense on this platform. Error message "DSO missing from command line" usually means wrong link order, you may easy google on this topic.

Comment: `PARQUET_LIBRARY_RELEASE` != `PARQUET_LIBRARIES_RELEASE`.

Comment: Note that parquet-cpp is archived and the source now lives in https://github.com/apache/arrow/tree/master/cpp/src/parquet

Answer (score 0):

As Uwe wrote in a comment, the https://github.com/apache/parquet-cpp repository is deprecated, and the Parquet C++ library is being developed as part of the Apache Arrow C++ codebase https://github.com/apache/arrow/tree/master/cpp. Can you try building based on that, and if you have trouble can you post on the dev@arrow.apache.org mailing list?

Comment: I builded exactly from this repository, ssory I gave the link just on parquet tool, not on exact rep where I built from. And as you can see from my update, the project is builded eventually, for me it just wonder why linker required .so lib together with .a lib for linking

Answer (score 0):

You have succeed to build the project when link with the *shared* (`.so`) libraries instead of the *static* (`.a`) ones.

(The command `find_library` actually looks for **one library**, which name is listed in NAMES option. In your case it found `.so` library because its name comes before the `.a` one).

Actually, both *shared* and *static* `parquet` libraries contain the **same** set of **symbols**, and both sets are **insufficient** for link. The difference is that the **shared** library **contains information**, where to find remaining symbols (in the `thrift` library in your case), but the static library doesn't.

For correctly link with the *static* libraries, you need to list dependent libraries **manually**.

---

On Windows `.lib` file may mean **either** a *static* library, or a import file for the *shared* (`.dll`) one. It seems that you link with the dynamic one (it has no `lib` *prefix*), which succeed like on Linux.